# Cannot specify a name to CSVDownload file

Tags: reactjs, csv

I am using CSVDownload from 'react-csv'.However I am not able to specify a filename to it like the one used in CSVLink. Is there an alternative way to specify a filename other than using the filename props which only works with CSVLink

```
`<CSVDownload data={this.state.data} />`
```

the CSVDownload is rendered only when the data is present.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
<CSVDownload data={this.state.data} filename={"my-file.csv"} />
```

Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv#--filename-props

Comment: It doesn't work. The prop filename is restricted to CSVLink

Comment: @Erick Sorry I didn't notice that, looking into the source code, unfortunately it doesn't support filename yet (https://github.com/abdennour/react-csv/blob/master/src/components/Download.js#L35), there is an issue submitted regarding that (https://github.com/abdennour/react-csv/issues/47)

Comment: It supports file name now